# How to combine onChange event for basic Validation Form in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to find the solution for How to Combine 2 events in Single OnChange event. I've tried many ways but none worked. Please help. All kind of help is appreciated.

I've commented the attempts i've tried.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

  class Form1 extends Component 
  {
    constructor(props) 
    {
        super(props)

        this.state = 
        {
             fields: {},
             errors: {},
             FirstName:'',
             LastName:'',
             Mobile: '',
             Department: ''
        }
    }

    // twoCalls = e => {

    //   //this.handleChange(field, e)
    //   this.handleMobileChange(e)
    //   this.handleLastnameChange(e)
    //   this.handleFirstnameChange(e)
    // }

    handleSubmit = (event) =>
    {
      // let twoCalls = this.state.handleChange
      // twoCalls = e => {
      //   this.handleChange(e)
      //  this.onSubmit
      // }
      // let twoCalls;
      // twoCalls = e => {
      //      //this.handleChange()

      //     this.handleMobileChange(e)
      //     this.handleLastnameChange(e)
      //     this.handleFirstnameChange(e)
      //   }

      //alert(this.state.FirstName +'  '+ this.state.LastName +'  '+this.state.Mobile );
     alert( `${this.state.FirstName} ${this.state.LastName} ${this.state.Mobile} ${this.state.Department} `)
      // console.log(this.handleFirstnameChange);
      // console.log(this.handleLastnameChange);
      // console.log(this.handleMobileChange);
      // console.log(this.handleDepartmentChange);

      // alert( console.log(this.handleFirstnameChange),
      //  console.log(this.handleLastnameChange),
      //  console.log(this.handleMobileChange));


        if(this.handleValidation())
        {
            alert("Form submitted");
           // alert( `${this.state.FirstName} ${this.state.LastName} ${this.state.Mobile} ${this.state.Department} `);
           //alert(this.state.FirstName +'  '+ this.state.LastName +'  '+this.state.Mobile );
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Form has errors.")
        }

        event.preventDefault()

    }
    handleValidation()
    {
           var fields = this.state.fields;
                 var errors = {};
                 var formIsValid = true;

                 //First Name
                  if(!fields["FirstName"])
                  {
                    formIsValid = false;
                    errors["FirstName"] = "Cannot be empty";
                  }

                  if(typeof fields["FirstName"] !== "undefined")
                  {
                    if(!fields["FirstName"].match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/))
                    {
                       formIsValid = false;
                       errors["FirstName"] = "Only letters";
                    }        
                  }
                    //Last Name
                  if(!fields["LastName"])
                  {
                    formIsValid = false;
                    errors["LastName"] = "Cannot be empty";
                  }

                  if(typeof fields["LastName"] !== "undefined")
                  {
                    if(!fields["LastName"].match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/))
                    {
                       formIsValid = false;
                       errors["LastName"] = "Only letters";
                    }        
                  }

                  //Mobile Number
                  if(!fields["Mobile"])
                  {
                    formIsValid = false;
                    errors["Mobile"] = "Cannot be empty";
                  }

                  if(typeof fields["Mobile"] !== "undefined")
                  {
                    if(!fields["Mobile"].match(/^[0-9\b]+$/))
                    {
                       formIsValid = false;
                       errors["Mobile"] = "Only Numbers";
                    }        
                  }
                  //Department
                  // if(!fields["Department"])
                  // {
                  //   formIsValid = false;
                  //   errors["Department"] = "Department Not Selected";
                  // }  //Working
                  //------------------------------------------------
                  // else ///Not-Working
                  //  {
                  //       formIsValid = true;
                  //       return formIsValid;
                  //       //errors["Department"] = "Select department";
                  //  }  
                  //-------------------------------------------------
                  // if(typeof fields["Department"] !== "undefined")
                  // {
                  //   if(fields["Department"].match("HR", "Technical", "Financial","Sales", "Management"))
                  //   {
                  //      formIsValid = true;
                  //      errors["Department"] = "Select department";
                  //   }    
                  // }
                  this.setState({errors: errors});
                  return formIsValid;
    }
    // handleChange(field, e)
    // {         
    //             let fields = this.state.fields;
    //             fields[field] = e.target.value;        
    //             this.setState({fields});


    // }
    handleonChange(field, e)
    {         
                var fields = this.state.fields;
                fields[field] = e.target.value;        
                this.setState({fields});


    }


    handleDepartmentChange = (event) =>
    {

        this.setState
        ({
            Department: event.target.value
        })
        event.preventDefault()
    }

    handleFirstnameChange = (event) =>
    {

        this.setState
        ({
            FirstName: event.target.value
        })
        event.preventDefault()
    }

    handleLastnameChange = (event) =>
    {

        this.setState
        ({
            LastName: event.target.value
        })
        event.preventDefault()
    }

    handleMobileChange = (event) =>
    {

        this.setState
        ({
            Mobile: event.target.value
        })
        event.preventDefault()
    }

    formatInput = (e) => {

      let checkIfNum;
      if (e.key !== undefined || e.keyCode !== undefined) {
        // Prevent characters that are numbers ("0-9")
        checkIfNum = e.key === "0" || e.key === "1" || e.key === "2" || e.key === "3" 
        || e.key === "4" || e.key === "5" || e.key === "6" || e.key === "7" || e.key === "8" 
        || e.key === "9" || e.key === "_" || e.key === "." || e.key === "-" || e.key === "@"
        || e.key === "," || e.keyCode === 32 ;
      }

      return checkIfNum && e.preventDefault();
    }
    formatNumInput = (e) => {
      // Prevent characters that are not numbers ("a-z", "A-Z") 
      let checkIfNum;
      if (e.keyCode !== undefined) {

        checkIfNum = e.keyCode === 47|| e.keyCode === 46 || e.keyCode === 47 || e.keyCode === 48
        || e.keyCode === 49 || e.keyCode === 50 || e.keyCode === 50 || e.keyCode === 51 || e.keyCode === 52
        || e.keyCode === 53 || e.keyCode === 54 || e.keyCode === 55 || e.keyCode === 56 || e.keyCode === 57 
        || e.keyCode === 65 || e.keyCode === 66 || e.keyCode === 67 || e.keyCode === 68 || e.keyCode === 69 
        || e.keyCode === 70 || e.keyCode === 71 || e.keyCode === 72 || e.keyCode === 73 || e.keyCode === 74
        || e.keyCode === 75 || e.keyCode === 76 || e.keyCode === 77 || e.keyCode === 78 || e.keyCode === 79 
        || e.keyCode === 80 || e.keyCode === 81 || e.keyCode === 82 || e.keyCode === 83 || e.keyCode === 84
        || e.keyCode === 85 || e.keyCode === 86 || e.keyCode === 87 || e.keyCode === 88 || e.keyCode === 89
        || e.keyCode === 90 || e.keyCode === 32;
      }
      return checkIfNum && e.preventDefault();
    }
  //   clickHandler=()=>{
  //     this.setState({


  //     })
  // }

    render() 
     {
        const {FirstName, LastName, Mobile, Department}= this.state
        return(
            <form name="Basic Information" className="Basic Information" onSubmit ={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}  style={{Align:"center"}}>
            <fieldset>
                <br />
                    <div style={{Align:"center"}}>
                        <label >First Name:<span style={{color: "red"}}>* </span> </label>  
                          <input
                            ref='FirstName'
                            type='text' value={FirstName} 
                            // onChange={this.handleFirstnameChange}
                            //onChange= {this.handleChange.bind(this, "FirstName")}
                             //onChange= {this.handleonChange.bind(this, "FirstName")} 
                           //onChange={ e =>{this.handleChange().bind(this, "FirstName"); this.handleFirstnameChange(e)} }
                           //onChange={this.twoCalls }
                           //onChange= {[this.handleChange().bind(this,"FirstName")], this.handleFirstnameChange()}
                           //onchange = function( { handleChange.bind(this, "FirstName"); this.handleFirstnameChange();}) 
                            value={this.state.fields["FirstName"]}
                            required
                            placeholder='Only Letters'
                            onKeyDown={ this.formatInput } 
                            style={{textAlign:"center"}}

                        />
                        <span style={{color: "red"}}>{this.state.errors["FirstName"]}</span>
                     </div>

            <br />
                    <div style={{Align:"center"}}>                       
                      <label >Last Name:<span style={{color: "red"}}>* </span> </label>
                          <input
                            ref='LastName'
                            type='text' value={LastName} 
                            onChange={this.handleLastnameChange}
                           // onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "LastName")} 
                            onChange={this.handleonChange.bind(this, "LastName")} 
                           //onChange={ e =>{this.handleChange().bind(this, "LastName"); this.handleLastnameChange(e)} }
                           //onChange={this.twoCalls }
                            value={this.state.fields["LastName"]}

                            required
                            placeholder='Only Letters' 
                            onKeyDown={ this.formatInput } 
                            style={{textAlign:"center"}}

                         />
                         <span style={{color: "red"}}>{this.state.errors["LastName"]}</span>

                    </div>

            <br />
                    <div style={{Align:"center-left"}} >
                        <label>Mobile No.:<span style={{color: "red"}}>* </span></label>      
                        <input 
                            ref='Mobile'
                            type= {Number} value={Mobile} 
                            onChange={this.handleMobileChange} 
                           //onChange= {this.handleChange.bind(this, "Mobile") } 
                           onChange= {this.handleonChange.bind(this, "Mobile") } 
                          // onChange={ e =>{this.handleChange().bind(this, "Mobile"); this.handleMobileChange(e)} }
                           //onChange={this.twoCalls }
                            value={this.state.fields["Mobile"]}
                            placeholder='Use Num-Pad Only'  
                           required
                           onKeyDown={ this.formatNumInput }
                           style={{textAlign:"center"}}

                        />
                         <span style={{color: "red"}}>{this.state.errors["Mobile"]}</span>
                    </div>

            <br />
                    <div style={{Align:"center-left"}}>

                        <label >Department:   <span style={{color: "red"}}>*  </span> </label> 
                            <select value={Department} onChange={this.handleDepartmentChange}> 
                               <option value="--"> -Select- </option> 
                               <option value="HR">HR</option>
                               <option value="Technical" >Technical</option>
                               <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
                               <option value="Management">Management</option>
                               <option value="Finance">Finance</option>

                           </select>
                            <span style={{color: "red"}}>{this.state.errors["Department"]}</span>
                    </div>

            <br/> 
            <div>

                   <button type="submit" style={{color: "Green"}}> Submit</button>
                   <br />
                   <br />
                   </div>
            </fieldset>
            <br/> 
            </form>
        )
    }
}
export default Form1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor method, you can have something like this state structure.

```
this.state = {
    fields: { name: '', email: '', phone: '', family: '' },
    errors: { name: '', email: '', phone: '', family: '' },
};
```

Here is the render method, including the "name" field. You can define other fields by just passing the value of that with the same definition in state , like 'family' , 'phone' ,'email' ,etc.

```
const {fields, errors = this.state;
return(
  <input
       className="with-label"
       type="text"
       onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'name')}
       placeholder="name"
       value={fields.name}
       name="input-name"
      />

 {errors.name && (
          <div className="alert-msg danger-msg">
            <i className="sj-Form-Alert" />
            <div className="alert-msg-text">{errors.name}</div>
          </div>
        )}
)
```

onChange method for all fields can be like this code below.

```
handleChange(field, e) {
      const { fields } = this.state;
      const { value } = e.target;
      fields[field] = value;
      this.setState({ fields }, () => this.handleValidation(field));
}

handleValidation(type) {
    const { errors, fields } = this.state;
    let formIsValid = true;
    switch (type) {
      case 'name':
        errors.name = '';
        if (!fields.name) {
          formIsValid = false;
          errors.name = 'please write the name';
        }
        if (fields.name && typeof fields.name !== 'undefined') {
          if (fields.name.length > 40) {
            formIsValid = false;
            errors.name = 'name should be more than 40 letters';
          }
        }
        break;
 case 'all': {/* add all validations */}
      default:
        break;
    }
    this.setState({ errors });
    return formIsValid;
}
onFormSubmit(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   if(this.handleValidation('all')){
     {/* do your stuff*/}
    }
}
```